# Error when using loop

Tags: javascript

I created a color slider (with the help of [this library](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker)), and I am now trying to make the color slider have a dynamic gradient. I've successfully implemented that, but when I try minimizing the code of the gradient (with a loop), I get into problems.

Here's the gradient layout. With every slider, there are x amount of colors that create a gradient. Then at both sides of the slider is a solid color. The code I have is extremely repetitive, so I tried creating loops. The loops look kind of ugly to me, and also, there's an error there that I'm not sure how to resolve.

This is what the error says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Here's the code for the rgb color space sliders. (I have 3 more color spaces.)

```
setGradient(slider[0], "right", [rgba2cssString(0, rgb.g, rgb.b), rgba2cssString(255, rgb.g, rgb.b)]);
setGradient(slider[1], "right", [rgba2cssString(rgb.r, 0, rgb.b), rgba2cssString(rgb.r, 255, rgb.b)]);
setGradient(slider[2], "right", [rgba2cssString(rgb.r, rgb.g, 0), rgba2cssString(rgb.r, rgb.g, 255)]);

slider[0].previousElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = rgba2cssString(0, rgb.g, rgb.b);
slider[0].nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = rgba2cssString(255, rgb.g, rgb.b);
slider[1].previousElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = rgba2cssString(rgb.r, 0, rgb.b);
slider[1].nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = rgba2cssString(rgb.r, 255, rgb.b);
slider[2].previousElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = rgba2cssString(rgb.r, rgb.g, 0);
slider[2].nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = rgba2cssString(rgb.r, rgb.g, 255);
```

Here's the attempted minified version (for all color spaces("Lab" is a color space)). It would help if `gradientObject` would also be generated using a loop.

```
var gradientObject = {
    rgb: [[[0, rgb.g, rgb.b], [255, rgb.g, rgb.b]],
        [[rgb.r, 0, rgb.b], [rgb.r, 255, rgb.b]],
        [[rgb.r, rgb.g, 0], [rgb.r, rgb.g, 255]]],

    hsl: [[[60, hsl.s, hsl.l], [120, hsl.s, hsl.l], [180, hsl.s, hsl.l], [300, hsl.s, hsl.l], [360, hsl.s, hsl.l]],
        [[hsl.h, 0, hsl.l], [hsl.h, 100, hsl.l]],
        [[hsl.h, hsl.s, 0], [hsl.h, hsl.s, 50], [hsl.h, hsl.s, 100]]],

    hsv: [[[0, hsv.s, hsv.v], [60, hsv.s, hsv.v], [120, hsv.s, hsv.v], [180, hsv.s, hsv.v], [300, hsv.s, hsv.v], [360, hsv.s, hsv.v]],
        [[hsv.h, 0, hsv.v], [hsv.h, 100, hsv.v]],
        [[hsv.h, hsv.s, 0], [hsv.h, hsv.s, 50], [hsv.h, hsv.s, 100]]],

    Lab: [[[0, Lab.a, Lab.b], [100, Lab.a, Lab.b]],
        [[Lab.L, -128, Lab.b], [Lab.L, 128, Lab.b]],
        [[Lab.L, Lab.a, -128], [Lab.L, Lab.a, 128]]],

    alpha: [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b, 1]]]
};

var sliderIndex = 0;
for (var colorSpaceGradient in gradientObject) {
    if (!gradientObject.hasOwnProperty(colorSpaceGradient)) return;

    var currentColorSpaceGradient = gradientObject[colorSpaceGradient],
        currentSlidersArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < currentColorSpaceGradient.length; i++) {
            var colorSliderGradient = currentColorSpaceGradient[i],
                colorSliderGradientArray = [];

            for (var x = 0; x < colorSliderGradient.length; x++) {
                console.log(colorSliderGradient[x]);
                colorSliderGradientArray.push(toCSSstring[colorSpaceGradient](colorSliderGradient[x]));
            }
            setGradient(slider[sliderIndex], 'right', colorSliderGradientArray);
            sliderIndex++;
        }

}
```

Full Code:  (Relevent code from line #95 - 204


#### codePen

My question is, how can I minimize the code without getting an error?

Comment: So what's the question/issue? If you're getting an error, you should share the error message.

Comment: @snookieordie You're right! Updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the inner workings of your code very well, I can see a few potential problems in your `hsva2cssString` function.

One thing I suspect is giving you trouble is your if-chain starting on line 365:

```
if (typeof h === 'object') { /*something*/ }
else if (Array.isArray(h)) { /*something else*/ }
```

You're never getting past the first clause.

A little quirk of javascript is that arrays are still considered objects. So even when `h` is an array, that first `if` block still goes through. Try running `typeof []` and you'll see what I mean. You have the right idea using `Array.isArray`, problem is you're never reaching that code. I would recommend either switching the order of those two clauses, or most likely removing the first one altogether, for the following reason:

On line 376, your call to `myColor.convertColor` is passing in `hsvObject` as an array (because of that first `if` clause). That function seems to expect the first argument as an object, not an array, which is getting you the error you mentioned.

Also, your hsv arrays have three elements, when the function is expecting a fourth value for alpha. I can foresee problems there, but I don't know if the solution is changing the arrays themselves, or changing how your function handles the arrays.

I'm wary to give you a direct solution without better knowledge of your code, but I think if you have a good look at the `if` blocks in `hsva2cssString`, you'll find what's causing the error.

Comment: Can you please show me an updated working codepen? Thanks!